# IE detection: what the heck does this mean?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I am looking at a piece of code which detects IE browser:

```
if (false || !!document.documentMode)
```

and I am not understanding the contraption. Why is it necessary to OR with false and use NOT twice?

If I simply loaded below file in IE9, FF or Opera, then IE would tell me that document mode was there, while the later two would say otherwise:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>function ld() {
        if (document.documentMode){
            document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = 'Document Mode detected'
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = 'No Document Mode'
        }
    }</script>
</head>
<body onload="ld()">
<p id="p1"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Is that not sufficient and why? It is not clear, because if I replaced the condition with the one in my original question, the result would be exactly the same. What am I missing?

Comment: Please change your title please to something more professional.

Comment: Where did you find the code?

Comment: 1) "*Why is it necessary to OR with false [...]*" It isn't. Best guess is that it's out of a habit of needing a boolean value for the `if` condition, which JavaScript doesn't require. 2) "*[...] and use NOT twice?*" [The operators convert the value to a boolean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2174297/how-to-use-the-double-not-operator-in-javascript), same as `Boolean(document.documentMode)`. Though, after removing the `false ||`, the `if` will do the boolean conversion itself, so they're also unnecessary.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Just what I thought, but overcomplication simply stunned me and the feeling was that I missed some secret wisdom. This would make a good answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is it necessary to OR with false [...]

It isn't necessary. The [`||` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR), given `false` for the 1st operand, [will always return the 2nd operand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966430/why-does-javascripts-or-return-a-value-other-than-true-false).

```
// lval || rval (minus short-circuiting)
function OR(lval, rval) {
    if (lval)
        return lval;
    else
        return rval;
}

OR(false, 'foo') // 'foo'
```

> [...] and use NOT twice?

This part [already has an answer here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2174297/how-to-use-the-double-not-operator-in-javascript).

Two [`!` operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_NOT_.28.21.29) together perform a "ToBoolean" type conversion, as a slighter shorter version of using [`Boolean()` without `new`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.6.1):

```
!!document.documentMode        // true/false
Boolean(document.documentMode) // true/false
```

---

Also, the `if` [will perform the same type conversion](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.5) itself.

```
2. If ToBoolean(GetValue(exprRef)) is true
```

So, when testing a single value for *truthiness*, the `!!` aren't necessarily either, as you suggested:

```
if (document.documentMode)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `document` is always defined, and the presence of its property `documentMode` is truthy, these are completely synonymous:

```
if (false || !!document.documentMode)
```

and:

```
if(document.documentMode)
```

(If `document` was possibly *undefined*, then the first code would fail altogether.)